# How to combine XT_DAC_Audio and A2DP BT-Sink on an ESP32?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32, a2dp

I am trying to combine two libraries on an ESP32.

I can run each of them alone, but not together.
I want to make a BT-Speaker as a Gift for my gf.

I want the speaker to play an Audio-file and afterwards run the BT-Sink.

But everytime I try to enable both at once (or after each other), the audio file is not playing and the BT-Script starts running directly.
When I comment one of them out, the other one works.

I hope someone can help. I am sure there is an easy fix.

Here is my .ino File:

`

```
// Playing a digital WAV recording repeatadly using the XTronical DAC Audio library
// prints out to the serial monitor numbers counting up showing that the sound plays 
// independently of the main loop
// See www.xtronical.com for write ups on sound, the hardware required and how to make
// the wav files and include them in your code

#include "BluetoothA2DPSink.h"
BluetoothA2DPSink a2dp_sink;


#include "SoundData.h"
#include "XT_DAC_Audio.h"
#include "Darthatmet.h"

XT_Wav_Class Darthatmet(Darth);       // verlinkung zur Darthatmet.h
XT_Wav_Class ForceWithYou(Force);     
XT_Sequence_Class Sequence;           
XT_DAC_Audio_Class DacAudio(25,0);    // Create the main player class object. Use GPIO 25, one of the 2 DAC pins and timer 0

                                      

void setup() {



Sequence.RepeatForever=false;
Sequence.AddPlayItem(&Darthatmet);
Sequence.AddPlayItem(&ForceWithYou);
DacAudio.Play(&Sequence);


  const i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
      .mode = (i2s_mode_t) (I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX | I2S_MODE_DAC_BUILT_IN),
      .sample_rate = 44100, // corrected by info from bluetooth
      .bits_per_sample = (i2s_bits_per_sample_t) 16, // the DAC module will only take the 8bits from MSB
      .channel_format =  I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
      .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_MSB,
      .intr_alloc_flags = 0, // default interrupt priority
      .dma_buf_count = 8,
      .dma_buf_len = 64,
      .use_apll = false
  };

  a2dp_sink.set_i2s_config(i2s_config);  
  a2dp_sink.start("DarthVader-BT");    

}


void loop() {

DacAudio.FillBuffer();                // Fill the sound buffer with data

}
```

`

I allready tried putting stuff inside the loop or using a true/false statement.
But it didn't work or i am just not educated enough with arduinoc-ode to do it :(

Comment: it looks like the song is played in loop() and the BT commands are in setup()

Comment: Yes, but thats how both have to be configured to work.
The Audio-File won't play if i put the "DacAudio.FillBuffer();" in Setup.
It is only played once because of the "Sequence.RepeatForever=false;" in the Setup.

And the BT-Sink part has to be in the Setup Section.

Comment: so you have to test in loop the state of playing and execute the BT command when the playing stopped

Comment: Yes, thats right. 
I found that there is "millis()" which i can use to count the time in milliseconds. I will try to use this as a timer. I know how long my Startup-Sound is. Perhaps i can set the script to start the BT-Sink after 6500 ms. While simultaneously playing the Startup-sound.

I read that a delay pauses the whole script. Means, EVERYTHING. Which is bad :/ 
So, millis() could be my fix for that. I will try later and post my findings ;)
Thx for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution :)
After some hours of testing I did it with "millis()".
It can be used to have a timer which runs in the "background".

I did it like this and it works like intended!

- It powers the ESP32 and plays the "Startup-Sound" which is made out of 2 Audio-snippets in HEX Format.
- while doing that it checks how much time in milliseconds has past since powerup.
- I know my Startup-Sound is ruffly 5 seconds long. So i set the "timer" to 5,5 Seconds.
- after it reached the 5,5 Seconds it starts the BT-Sink AND sets a flag named "btstarted". The flag needs to be false to trigger the BT-Sink start.
  At first i did not used this flag. The Result was that i could see the BT-Device but can't connect cause it kept restarting after 5,5 seconds.
  With this flag, it will only start once per powerup. Which is nice :)

Next step are programmable LEDs (ws2812b) and 3D-Design/Printing the Housing :)

Here is my code:

```
#include "BluetoothA2DPSink.h"
#include "SoundData.h"
#include "XT_DAC_Audio.h"
#include "Darthatmet.h"

BluetoothA2DPSink a2dp_sink;

XT_Wav_Class Darthatmet(Darth);       // verlinkung zur Darthatmet.h
XT_Wav_Class ForceWithYou(Force);     
XT_Sequence_Class Sequence;           
XT_DAC_Audio_Class DacAudio(25,0);    // Create the main player class object. Use GPIO 25, one of the 2 DAC pins and timer 0

bool btstarted = false;

void setup() {

Sequence.RepeatForever=false;
Sequence.AddPlayItem(&Darthatmet);
Sequence.AddPlayItem(&ForceWithYou);
DacAudio.Play(&Sequence);


const i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t) (I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX | I2S_MODE_DAC_BUILT_IN),
    .sample_rate = 44100, // corrected by info from bluetooth
    .bits_per_sample = (i2s_bits_per_sample_t) 16, // the DAC module will only take the 8bits from MSB
    .channel_format =  I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
    .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_MSB,
    .intr_alloc_flags = 0, // default interrupt priority
    .dma_buf_count = 8,
    .dma_buf_len = 64,
    .use_apll = false
    };

a2dp_sink.set_i2s_config(i2s_config);
//a2dp_sink.set_mono_downmix(true);

}


void loop() {

DacAudio.FillBuffer();                // Fill the sound buffer with data, start Playback
unsigned long zeit = millis();
if (zeit >= 5500 and btstarted == false) {
  a2dp_sink.start("DarthVaderrr");
  btstarted = true;
  }

}
```